# What is the antonym of DRM-free?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

The term DRM-free, with DRM standing for digital rights management, is commonly used online to refer to content which can be downloaded and transferred by the user. Content which is not DRM-free cannot be downloaded and is only accessible on the particular app or website of the content provider. My question is, what is the antonym of DRM-free? A single word term would be desired as the phrases I considered sound quite clunky and verbose. An example usage would be:

> Sadly, Jack could not transfer his music files to his friend as they were _______

Comment: The efficient antonym is simply *DRM*, where *DRM* stands for 'digital rights **managed**'.

Comment: *"Not purchased"* is the correct antonym, and letting the manufactures know that is the way to make the point moot. Alternately you can use something like *"last product on el shelfarino"* if you're not into the whole brevity thing.

Comment: Ruakh's answer is excellent but you could also change the wording leading up to DRM like so: `Sadly, Jack could not transfer his music files to his friend because they (are protected by | use) DRM.`

Comment: I'm guessing "victims of an ill conceived anti-sharing paradigm that demonstrably lowers growth and profits in the music industry" is a little too verbose for your taste?

Comment: @corsiKlauseHoHoHo Sadly yes

Comment: How about DRMP - Digital Rights Management Protected?

Comment: DRM-infested. It’s “Digital Restrictions Management”, after all.

Comment: *DRMed* would be the verb, I believe.

Comment: CRAP -  Consumer Rights Aren't Permitted

Comment: This is english.se; please get the acronym right. It's Digital *Restriction* Management -- DRM conveys no "rights" whatsoever, it exists only to take them away.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The most common term seems to be [*DRM protected*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22DRM-protected+content%22). Other relatively common terms, in approximate descending order, include [*DRM locked*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22DRM-locked+content%22), [*DRM enabled*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22DRM-enabled+content%22), [*DRMed*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22DRMed+content%22), and [*DRM encumbered*](https://www.google.com/search?q="drm-encumbered+content").

A few notes:

- *DRM protected* seems to be relatively neutral, whereas *DRM locked*, *DRMed*, and *DRM encumbered* seem to be slightly pejorative and *DRM enabled* seems to be slightly, um, ameliorative.
- *DRM enabled* is a bit ambiguous, in that it's also used to describe devices that *support* DRM. But the intended meaning is usually clear from context.
- As Martin Smith mentions above, DRM can take a number of different forms, and doesn't necessarily prevent downloading.

Comment: Among those who would use a term like "DRM-free", "DRM-encumbered" is not so uncommon as an antonym. In contrast, "DRM-protected" has a more positive connotation, by my reading of it.

Comment: @OleksandrR.: Presumably "DRM-protected" was intended to have a positive connotation ("protection" is good, right?), but in practice I think it's basically used neutrally. As for "DRM-encumbered" -- I'll add that, thanks. But Google-searches suggest that it's not as common as the other terms I'd listed.

Comment: Among the sites I typically visit (like Arstechnica) the term I often read is DRM-crippled (though, that may be just my brain translating anything DRM-**** into DRM-crippled)

Comment: My first instinct would be "DRM-ridden", just as pejorative as "DRM-encumbered" but faster to say.

Comment: I use "DRM laden" myself.

Comment: in the context, the DRM is preventing the user from doing stuff, and are therefore *encumbering* Jack.

Comment: @Medinoc I have also come across some more negative terms being used such as DRM infested and DRM infected.

Comment: Wouldn’t these words have to be hyphenated (DRM-protected, DRM-enabled, etc.)? (honest question, I’m a non-native speaker)

Comment: @unor: There's a lot of variation in that respect, but the most common recommendation is that such compounds be hyphenated when used attributively (before a noun; e.g., "a DRM-protected file"), but not when used predicatively (elsewhere; e.g., "the file is DRM protected"). (Personally, I tend to hyphenate regardless -- "this file is DRM-protected" -- but I decided that I should follow the standard recommendation here, since I didn't have any specific reason not to.)

Comment: I'd have been inclined to phrase it as "subject to DRM"

Comment: It may not be as common as some other terms, but "DRM-encumbered" is used by the FSF and other relatively authoritative (well compared to some guy's blog post) sources such as wikipedia: [See e.g. here](https://www.defectivebydesign.org/faq). When I read the question title it would also have been my first choice, followed by DRM-protected.

Comment: I’d not use “DRM protected” – sure, it’s protected, but from whom? From the user. Applying this to something a person wishes to use is most certainly not neutral, but rather misleading.

Comment: "DRM encumbered" is exactly what I thought of when I saw the question title.

Answer (score 22):

"DRM-locked", especially if you're looking for a single word similar to "DRM-free". For example, Kindle books, which are under DRM, will give an error saying "This book is locked by DRM" or something similar when you attempt to edit them with an ebook-managing program.

In fact, "under DRM" also works if there are instances where a single word doesn't sound right.

"DRM-limited" is also an option, but it's less clearly an antonym of "DRM-free" and it's similar enough in form to the better "DRM-locked" that there's probably no need to ever use it.

Answer (score 20):

Copy Protected

I've seen this definition for it:

> A class of methods for preventing incompetent pirates from stealing software and legitimate customers from using it. Considered silly.
>
> ---
>
> [The New Hacker's Dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=g80P_4v4QbIC&pg=PA126&lpg=PA126&dq=A%20class%20of%20methods%20for%20preventing%20incompetent%20pirates%20from%20stealing%20software%20and%20legitimate%20customers%20from%20using%20it.%20Considered%20silly.&source=bl&ots=6odmnumvR5&sig=NCcD1rgyp936xRNUGEQX5FU0NzY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBnfCiptrJAhVRw2MKHW36DFcQ6AEIGTAB#v=onepage&q&f=false), third edition, by Eric S. Raymond

Comment: The New Hacker's Dictionary is getting rather old, and language changes. I think most people these days will say DRM-something instead. The rest of the quote is spot on, though.

Comment: @StigHemmer Sure, but I don't think "copy-protected" sounds dated.

Comment: The term DRM was invented decades after copy protected had been in frequent use. I tend to think of DRM as preventing the copying of passive media like movies and books by using flags ("don't copy this") and digital signatures ("this belongs to alice"), whereas copy protection was physically preventing a piece of software/firmware from running other than on the media it was supplied on (by making the media non-standard so regular OS-supplied copying tools didn't work).  I believe the distinction is useful, and still stands.

Answer (score 9):

DRM-laden

especially in order to bring attention to some cumbersome "feature"

Comment: I have never heard anyone who is not a journalist use the word "laden".

Comment: I see it in books/fiction, but "laden" is usually used to imply a large number of items, a trying emotional burden, or a great weight. For all its downsides, DRM is at least... not particularly heavy.

Answer (score 6):

How about "DRM-protected"? For example:

DRM-protected titles
https://www.ucl.ac.uk/library/electronic-resources/e_book_guides/T-and-F

Comment: "Protected" implies a modicum of effectiveness and is a misleading term. The only thing being protected is the distributor's ability to arbitrarily restrict the ways their customers can experience the content.

Answer (score 5):

For a more loaded term, there are those who refer to such things as:

*Defective By Design*

This is admittedly meant to be a non-neutral term, and is more of a phrase, but is a non-uncommon term, especially in certain circles.

Comment: Note that the Free Software Foundation's [Defective by Design](https://www.defectivebydesign.org/faq) campaign actually uses the term "DRM-encumbered" (which appears in the accepted answer).

Comment: Although this is true, literal signification of defective by design can very easily be used to refer to other concepts such as planned obsolescence or crippleware too so this only fits in limited contexst.